# Why does Interpreter fail intermittently?

Tags: date-and-time, interpreter

I notice that, when I process CSV files and using `Interpreter`, I sometimes get Interpreter failure for certain dates as shown below:

[image]

I am using the following `Interpreter` expression on the data imported in CSV format:

```
time = 
  Interpreter["DateTime"][myData[[startofdatasample  ;; endofdataSample, 5]]];
```

Why is it able to interpret some dates and not others? When I run the same file again, it may interpret all the dates correctly, or it may fail in different places, so I believe the input is properly formatted. it seems like a timeout or a failure to reach a server.

Appreciate some feedback. I am fairly new to Mathematica and am trying to understand these intermittent failures. I am sure it is something I am failing to setup properly.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the lines on your file that succeed and others that fail? How long is the file?

Comment: I would contact technical support. If you want anyone to even be able to help you here it'd be best if you provided the exact file you're using to reproduce this.

Comment: Here is the example file https://spaces.hightail.com/space/b1Nr8GNP5m